Matrix visual showing same URL on both parent and child rows
I want to build a matrix visual in which, upon clicking on a parent row to drop it down, it displays the URL values associated with the child rows; however when I do so, I find that parent categories display the same url than the first child row, as shown in the image below.

I would like to know if there is any workaround so that Category rows don't display any URL. Turning off the subtotals won't work, as there are other columns in the matrix that need to display that number.


Did you try to turn off row subtotals in the matrix settings?


Sorry, I forgot to mention I need subtotals for other columns. I edited my post.
